# NOT NULL constraint failed: stories_story.url

Tags: python, django

Could someone please explain why I am getting a NOT NULL constraint failed: stories_story.url error.

I get the error when I try to 'sumbit' a story (localhost/story)

Here are some files. If you need more please let me know.

**models.py**

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=350)
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    points = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'moderated_stories')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'liked_stories')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    @property 
    def domain(self):
        return urlparse(self.url).netloc

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "stories"
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url = "/login/")
    def story(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = StoryForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                story = form.save(commit = False)
                story.moderator = request.user
                story.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            form = StoryForm()
        return render(request, 'stories/story.html', {'form': form})
```

Edit:

I completely removed the URLField as I no longer don't need it. I ran the migration and everything worked fine. Except I still get the same error : NOT NULL constraint failed: stories_story.url. I don't understand where this issue is coming from in my code.

Comment: You probably added `null=True, blank=True` to URLField after table has been created. Type `ALTER TABLE stories_story ALTER COLUMN url DROP NOT NULL` command in your database shell via `python manage.py dbshell` or better yet use [south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html).

Comment: I did! Is there a fix?

Comment: what's your database server? MySQL, postgreSQL, sqlite?

Comment: I'm using standard sqlite! I tried looking at south, except you have to downgrade to django<1.7

Comment: @ozgur i put the command into the dbshell, but nothing happens. I just tried to put it in 'python manage.py shell', however, it returned a syntax error with an arrow pointing to TABLE. Issue still isn't resolved. Should I be removing the constraints from the url field in models before I run these commands?

Comment: Django has built in migrations since Django 1.7, you don't need to use South any more. If you use the db shell you need a semicolon at the end of the command: `ALTER COLUMN url DROP NOT NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you're using migrations, check if there is migrations dir inside your app and if there are some migrations in that directory (files other than `__init__.py`).

If not, you're not using migrations for that application yet, so to get it working, you must roll-back your `models.py` to state corresponding to your database state. After doing that, run `python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name` and restore your current state of models.py.

After doing that, run `python manage.py migrate your_app_name --fake-initial`, that will store your initial migration in your migrations history.

If there are at least one migration alread, or if you're finished all "If not" section, run `python ./manage.py makemigrations your_app_name` to create new migrations and `python ./manage.py migrate` to apply them. You should make and apply migrations after changes in your `models.py`.

Comment: I have migrations other than the __init__.py file. I'm still getting the same error after doing the last paragraph of what you recommended. Anything else I could do?

Comment: How many migrations do you have? Can you show them on your question?